# Type Decaying - What It Is And Why Is It There?

Tags: c++, types

I was surprised the type decay is not explained very well on SO or elsewhere, maybe I did not search using the correct terms or maybe I'm not understanding the whole thing correctly. My **question is: what it is, how (why) did it get there and what are the rules of it?**

---

If you are wondering why I'm asking, below is my sob type decay story (**not** the subject of the question, though):

I was recently struggling with some simple templates and I wanted to do something like this:

```
template <class FunObj>
double DoStuff(FunObj fob) // note that this returns double, not FunObj, as e.g. std::for_each() does
{ /* ... */ }

struct MyFunObj {
    mutable size_t num_invoked; // collect usage statistics

    MyFunObj()
        :num_invoked(0)
    {}

    bool operator ()(double some_arg) const
    {
        ++ num_invoked;
        return sin(some_arg) < .5;
    }
};
```

This is all nice, there is a template function expecting a function object, and a function object. The function was designed to not return the state of the function object (as similar functions often do; it was returning a result of some intricate computation instead), so I thought I would specialize it for a *reference* to the object. But the type decay gets in the way (or at least that is my understanding of it):

```
MyFunObj fob;
DoStuff(fob); // passed by value, usage statistics are lost (no surprise here)

MyFunObj &ref = fob;
DoStuff(ref); // MyFunObj& decays to MyFunObj, usage statistics are lost

DoStuff(static_cast<MyFunObj&>(fob)); // again, hampered by type decay
```

I know how to solve this, so please do not reply how. I'm only interested in type decay as such and this is here only as a motivation of my question / an illustrative example. If you like, you can post some hate for my use of `mutable`.

Comment: Your case doesn't look to be related to type decay in my opinion... It has to do with the fact that passing a reference to a function that take its parameter by value doesn't change magically that argument type into pass-by-reference. Type decay would be how an array can decay into a pointer (i.e. `char[]` into `char*`).

Comment: Use `std::ref(fob)` when passing it as an argument. Ta-da!

Comment: @JBL I think the OP's question is why isn't `FunObj` a reference type in the second and third instantiations (the first is somewhat trivial to understand).

Comment: @JBL: It's reference decay; the template argument is deduced as `MyFunObj` even though the function argument type (used for deduction) is `MyFunObj&`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Oh right, there still is the template arg deduction. Missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSeymour does that somehow change validity of Agnew's answer?

Comment: @theswine: No. "Decay" isn't a well-defined word, but the answer gives a good description what happens in this situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't really think your question shows an example of type decay. The term "decay" is commonly used to refer to the standard function-to-pointer, array-to-pointer and lvalue-to-rvalue conversions. What you're hitting are the rules for template argument deduction.

The thing is that template argument deduction is based on *types,* not on *value categories.* The type of `ref` in your example is `MyFunObj`, and it's an *lvalue* of that type (BTW, exactly the same holds for `fob`). Since deduction works on types, `FunObj` is deduced to the *type* of `ref`, which is indeed `MyFunObj`.

Before C++11, there was no way to deduce a reference type. C++11 changed this with "forwarding references." These have introduced a special case where passing an lvalue of type `U` to a function parameter declared as `T&&` (where `T` is a template parameter of the function template) uses `U&` as the type for deduction instead of `U`. But that's a special rule, an exception. Normally, value categories don't play a role in type deduction.

Comment: +1 I suspect this is *exactly* where the disconnect in understanding is. nice answer.

Comment: All right, yes, that seems to be my answer. As I said, I was not really sure that I'm understanding it correctly, thanks for a great explanation!

Comment: @theswine I know you mentioned you know how to solve it, but here's one way to do that which could also serve as food for thought: calling `DoStuff<MyFunObj&>(fob)`. And then think about what declaring a variable of type `FunObj` inside `DoStuff` means, and how intuitive it would be if references were normally part of the deduction process.

Comment: @Angew well, yes, understandably. But to me, that would be more expected behavior - if I specialized it with a reference, then `FunObj` is a reference and if I declare an instance of it in the template function, it is a reference - makes more sense than silently removing the reference IMO. But I guess it would make common code plagued with casts to remove all the references, as well as source of "unexpected behavior" opposite of my case :).

Comment: @theswine Additionally, there would be the question of whether "reference" or "lvalue" should be the source of `&` in the template parameter. A distinction which is not really present in standard C++ so far. Consider passing `*p` for some pointer `p`. Lvalue? yes. Reference? no ... or is it? What if `p` was a smart pointer; these have to return references to return lvalues. Feels like a can of worms to me.